# Get Network Traffic

Tags: linux, command-line, networking

Is there a command line program for Linux that will tell me how much is currently being uploaded and downloaded (ie the network "speed").

I want a program that runs, tells me the traffic, then stops. All I've been able to find are live updating applications. (I want to be able to use it similarly to, for example, free, and not, for example, top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iptable rules can be used to count the packets coming in and going out. I have used this capability to troubleshoot network/firewall issue and not for the bandwidth monitoring.

However, iptables does provide options to

> create new custom chains
>   create IP based rules
>   view counters
>   reset counters

So using iptable options, a script can do the job for you. An example is given on [linux.com](http://www.linux.com/archive/articles/50649) on how to use these iptable options.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `netstat`. A few common switches I use:

- `-n` , which tells it not to resolve names and protocols.
- `-a` , which tells it to also report ports that are listening.
- `-t` , which tells it to just report TCP ports; there's a lot of other stuff reported by netstat

Comment: If I run `netstat -t`, would the download speed be the sum of the Recv-Q column, and the upload speed be the sum of the Send-Q column?

Comment: @Jeffrey Aylesworth: i think netstat falls more under the 'top' category than the 'free' category.

Comment: @quack: not at all. Are you confusing it with nettop maybe?

Comment: The Recv-Q column is the amount of data that the host has received, but hasn't been processed by the program yet. The Send-Q column shows how much data the program has asked the system to send, but hasn't been sent yet(usually due to bandwidth limitations, but sometimes due to having the command sent at exactly the right time).

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try with "**vnstat**". get it from sourceforge or freshmeat.Wonderful commandline utility to solve your owes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit too much like top, but [`nload`](http://www.roland-riegel.de/nload/) does a decent job.

Comment: That looks good, but it needs to run, tell me the traffic, then exits. I need to be able to read it from a script.